# ANTLR4 - Make space optional between tokens

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I have the following grammar:

```
grammar Hello;

prog:   stat+ EOF;

stat:   DELIMITER_OPEN expr DELIMITER_CLOSE;
expr:   NOTES COMMA value=VAR_VALUE #delim_body;

VAR_VALUE:  ANBang*;
NOTES:  WS* 'notes' WS*;
COMMA:  ',';
DELIMITER_OPEN: '<<!';
DELIMITER_CLOSE:    '!>>';

fragment ANBang:    AlphaNum | Bang;
fragment AlphaNum:  [a-zA-Z0-9];
fragment Bang:  '!';

WS    : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

Parsing the following works:

```
<<! notes, Test !>>
```

and the variable value is "Test", however, the parser fails when I eliminate the space between the DELIMITER_OPEN and NOTES:

```
<<!notes, Test !>>
```

> line 1:3 mismatched input 'notes' expecting NOTES

Comment: Since you skip whitespaces try without `WS*` in the `NOTES` rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *yet another* case of badly ordered lexer rules.

When the lexer scans for the next token, it first tries to find the rule which will match the *longest* token. If several rules match, it will disambiguate by choosing the *first* one in definition order.

`<<! notes, Test !>>` will be tokenized as such:
`DELIMITER_OPEN` `NOTES` `COMMA` `VAR_VALUE` `WS` `DELIMITER_CLOSE`

This is because the `NOTES` rule can match the following:

```
<<! notes, Test !>>
   \____/
```

Which *includes* the whitespace. If you remove it:

```
<<!notes, Test !>>
```

Then both the `NOTES` and `VAR_VALUE` rules can match the text `notes`, and, `VAR_VALUE` is defined *first* in the grammar, so it gets precedence. The tokenization is:
`DELIMITER_OPEN` `VAR_VALUE` `COMMA` `VAR_VALUE` `WS` `DELIMITER_CLOSE`
and it doesn't match your `expr` rule.

Change your rules like this to fix the problem:

```
NOTES:  'notes';
VAR_VALUE:  ANBang+;
```

Adding `WS*` to other rules doesn't make much sense, since `WS` is skipped. And declaring a token as having a possible zero width `*` is also meaningless, so use `+` instead. Finally, *reorder* the rules so that the most specific ones match fist.

This way, `notes` becomes a *keyword* in your grammar. If you don't want it to be a keyword, remove the `NOTES` rule altogether, and use the `VAR_VALUE` rule with a predicate. Alternatively, you could use lexer modes.

Comment: Thank you.  If the VAR_VALUE token could contain something like "Test me", would I have to stop ignoring white spaces, or how can I capture a value of "notes" that could be any string, with spaces, punctuation, etc.

Comment: I'd either put *everything* into one `NOTES` token, or if you insist on splitting it for the parser stage, the easiest way is to use lexer modes.

Comment: Could you create an example to point me in the right direction? If you prefer, I can always create a separate question.

Comment: You just push a lexer mode on `<<!`, you pop it on `!>>`, this lets you change the lexer rules inside some constructs. Google for lexer modes, then try to implement a solution, and if you still have an issue, then post another question with the specific issue.